# execute a query right after connexion in cakePHP

Tags: php, database, unicode, cakephp, utf-8

I want to execute a mysql query right after connecting to the database to enable utf-8

```
SET NAMES 'utf-8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

and i want an answer either for a specific model all for the whole application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your database file set the encoding to utf8. This will cause cakephp to run the set names query.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/331/Cake-Database-Configuration